# SQL - Java : Invalid column name :Invalid column name

Tags: java, sql

```
protected String getSQLCarFinder()
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("select distinct T1.ASSET_AMT c1, T1.NAME c2, T1.ALIAS_NAME c3 ");
    sb.append("from {0}.CARFINDERDB T1 ");
    sb.append("where T1.ASSET_AMT=? ");
    sb.append(" and T1.OU_TYPE_CD <> ''NOC'' ");
    sb.append(" and " + IRDataSource.getLengthFunctionName() + "(T1.ASSET_AMT) <= " + CARFINDER_CODE_MAX_LENGTH);
    return sb.toString();
    }
```

Error:

```
[2014-01-24 10:42:20,238] Thread-66 ERROR util.XNAMEDbLogProcessor - XNAMEDbLogProcessor :: logItem : ExceptionAn unexpected token "NOC" was found following "nvalid column name '".  Expected tokens may include:  ",".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.7.112
[2014-01-24 10:42:20,238] Thread-66 ERROR util.XNAMEDbLogProcessor - XNAMEDbLogProcessor :: logItem : An error occurred while logging data to the database: An unexpected token "NOC" was found following "nvalid column name '".  Expected tokens may include:  ",".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.7.112: Data={[2014-01-24-10.42.17.318000] [server_common_name] [common_name] [] [99999] [0] [] [] [] [E] [INTRANET] [2014-01-24] [10:42:20] [CDLT] [Account : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'NOC'.] }
[2014-01-24 10:42:22,458] RMI TCP Connection(98501)-172.28.24.27 DEBUG dataaccess.NewCarViewDataSource -  NewCarViewDataSource:: connect : IR connect siebel without user  and password
[2014-01-24 10:42:22,477] RMI TCP Connection(98501)-172.28.24.27 DEBUG dataaccess.IRDataSource -  IRDataSource:: getLengthFunctionName : Lenght function name:LEN
[2014-01-24 10:42:22,478] RMI TCP Connection(98501)-172.28.24.27 ERROR server.AssociateCodeListRetrieveCommand - AssociateCodeListRetrieveCommand ::executeINTRANETCall : Exception Invalid column name 'NOC'.
[2014-01-24 10:42:22,481] RMI TCP Connection(98501)-172.28.24.27 DEBUG server.REPDatabaseCommand -  REPDatabaseCommand :: executeCall : Time to execute CDLT transaction = 23
[2014-01-24 10:42:23,144] Thread-65 DEBUG util.XNAMEAlertLogProcessor - XNAMEAlertLogProcessor :: logItem : Error alert log processor: ALERT-001 -s "Error occurred in AssociateCodeListInfo" Date:     Time:   Server name: server_common_name Client name: common_name


User id: **strong text**
```

I tried

```
sb.append(" and T1.OU_TYPE_CD <> /'NOC/' ");
sb.append(" and T1.OU_TYPE_CD <> ''NOC'' ");
sb.append(" and T1.OU_TYPE_CD <> 'NOC' ");
```

Nothing working. What am I doing wrong here? `T1.OU_TYPE_CD`  is the column name and `NOC` is the value in it. I want to check `T1.OU_TYPE_CD` value is `NOT NOC`.

Comment: Can you print the string out ?

Comment: are you sure the problem is there? what goes after that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the double single quotes around `NOC`:

```
sb.append(" and T1.OU_TYPE_CD <> 'NOC' ");
```

Your delimiter for the outer string is a double quote, so there is no need to escape the single quote.

Comment: @user3232895 . . . It shouldn't be the same error, because `NOC` could not be a column name in this query.

Answer (score 0):

Column names don't need `''`:

```
sb.append(" and T1.OU_TYPE_CD <> NOC ");
```

**EDIT:**

Compiler is interpreting `NOC` as a column name. If `NOC` is a `string` value, your problem I think would be an escaping problem.

Try:

`sb.append(" and T1.OU_TYPE_CD <> \'NOC\' ");`

or this:

`sb.append(" and T1.OU_TYPE_CD NOT IN ('NOC') ");`

or setting an `aux` string directly:

```
String aux = " and T1.OU_TYPE_CD <> 'NOC' ";
sb.append(aux);
```

Comment: Its not column name, NOC is the data in column T1.OU_TYPE_CD

Answer (score 0):

This should have worked.

sb.append(" and T1.OU_TYPE_CD <> 'NOC' ");

Are you sure you are getting the same error message?